# How to update feature of a web-app which is built in laravel but deployed on multiple client servers (Like- Hostinger, BlueHost, Godaddy etc)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a project where we have a product that we are selling to clients and basically it is same web-app with just different client logos, name and some minor changes.

Let's say we have an app that facilitates billing and invoicing. All of our clients are using this app and the only difference is that all apps have their own customer logos and name. It is hard to maintain multiple different projects. I mean if we have a new feature to implement or a bug fix, it is very difficult to copy code and paste it in all apps one by one.

So i just wanted to know, if there is any easy way to manage projects like this?

Comment: You could abstract the core features of your application and make them a composer package. You would just update the core package then instead of copy&pasting code around.

Comment: Is there any tutorial how to do that? I'm very new to all these.

Comment: If you search for tutorials, like *how to create composer package* you will certainly find some. If you add *in Laravel* to your search terms you'll find even more specialized tutorials. Just go ahead and seek out a couple. Don't just use one source of knowledge if your company depends on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the options, that you could use:

1. If logo is the only thing that changes, then there are two options. Use the same name and place for each client or just add .env variable like LOGO_PATH=public/path/to_logo (not the best option) just to get image path
2. If multiple clients use the same server/database, create client_configs table and store each client info about logo, name or other client related configs there. No need to alter code between clients
3. If code logic changes between clients, add .env variable to enable disable different sections or alterations
4. Create plugin for core features. If you have to fix bugs, then just update plugin and nothing else